# form post wipes out a file-scoped variable

Tags: php, file, variables

When I POST a form to the same .php file a file-scope variable is null when it shouldn't be.

**includefile.php:**

```
 <?php

     $foo = " ";
 ?>
```

**doIt.php:**

```
<?php

    echo $foo;

echo <<<_END
  <form action="doIt.php" method="post"><pre>
    $nameLabel  : <input type="text" name=$nameLabel />
    <input type="submit" name="addrecord" value="ADD RECORD" />
```

_END;

**index.php**

```
<?php
   require_once 'includefile.php';

   $foo = "Set now.";  

   require_once 'doIt.php';
?>
```

The first time it loads, index.php causes $foo to echo and it says "Set now."
But when I press the submit button on the form -- $foo is empty.
Why does re-entry into doIt.php kill the value of $foo?
NOTE: the require_once changed nothing -- still same problem.

My guess is that the form POST and the resulting re-entry into the same .php file
sets up a new call frame on the stack with everything set to nothing.

Comment: The form technically doesn't post back to the same file - rather than posting to 'index.php' you are posting to 'doit.php', which is a `require_once` from the index file. I don't think there is a major issue there, but something to consider.

Comment: you changed all of the code you posted.

Comment: there is no such thing as "file-scoped". an include statement is the same as copying all the code in the included file right where your include statement is.

Comment: I modified the code to prove to myself the first pass through doIt.php picks up the value of $foo correctly.  But re-entry into doIt.php caused by submitting the form wipes out the value of $foo.  That kinda proves my theory that a new call frame is set up on the stack that wipes out $foo.  If I do require_once 'includefile.php' at the top of doIt.php, I still get the same problem. As to acceptance and faq etc. I am not qualified, rather I do not feel qualified, to rate any responses. I'm too much of a beginner and you'd force me to lie that I 'liked' an answer. Will keep it in mind though!

Comment: when you post your form to doit.php, no variables from your previous call to the server will exists anymore. as you can see $foo should not be set when running doit.php alone as it is never set in that file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your form needs to be submitted to 'index.php' and not 'doit.php'. In the 'doit.php' file, `$foo` is set to empty string from the `require_once` file, and is never set through 'index.php' as you might have expected. So:

`<form action="index.php" method="post">`

Comment: Okay,  what I REALLY want is to have $foo's value, once it is set the first time, inside index.php (the first time the page loads) - I then want $foo to be available in every other file in the project after its value gets set to 'Set now'.  That's why I put $foo in includefile.php, and originally then had require_once 'includefile.php' in every other file where I would need to access $foo.  But I find that a form POST wipes out $foo.  And I don't know why.